# X86: Comparison of last six bytes of a double type number with zero

Tags: assembly, x86, ieee-754

What is the purpose of the following code?

A partial of an 64 bit `double` type number is compared with zero.
Does it exactly mean `ZF= if(L_double_x==0.0)` ?

This code is a machine compiled code.

```
; process of initialization
; ...
cmp word ptr [L_double_x_continue],0000h
jnz L13

L13:
....



L_double_x:
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
L_double_x_continue: 
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
        db  00h;
```

Comment: What is written to `L_double_x`? This could make sense for some specifics tricks, it's not testing `L_double_x==0.0` though.

Comment: @harold this data is coming from an external code. This value is copied from a function argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it exactly mean `ZF= if(L_double_x==0.0)` ?

No. A IEEE 754 double number is 0 (+0) if all the bits of the number are 0's. Besides, the comparison is with 16 bits from this number, which lie somewhere within the mantissa. More context (code) is needed to figure out what kind of trick this is employing.

Comment: `-0.0 == 0.0`, so testing an IEEE float / double / long double for equality to `0.0` requires you ignore the sign bit.